# NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element error while scraping the top 20 holder using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I try to scrape the top 20 holder of a token on the ERC-20 chain. I use for that selenium.
It seems like the xpath's dont load/didnt have enough time?

I try to load this page:
https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7#balances

I tried it with implicit wait and with explicit wait. I can even see, when I run the webdriver that the side is load, but it never found the path...

Code with explicity wait:

```
options = Options()
ptions.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-using")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7#balances")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10, poll_frequency=1)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="maintable"]/div[3]/table/tbody/')))
```

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Yep not even a message...

Code with implicit:

```
options = Options()
ptions.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-using")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7#balances")
for i in range(1,20):
            req = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="maintable"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr['+str(i)+']/td[2]/span/a')
```

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="maintable"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/a"}
```

So like I say it looks like the driver has not enough time to load the page but even with 20,30,... secounds they dont find the path.

Also when I copy the xpath from the browser opened by the script I can find the xpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Table is present inside an `iframe` you need to switch to iframe first to access the table.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`()

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibility_of_all_elements_located`()

**code**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7#balances")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"tokeholdersiframe")))
elements=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="maintable"]/div[3]/table/tbody//tr/td[2]//a')))
for ele in elements:
    print(ele.get_attribute('href'))
```

---

If you want to fetch **first 20 token** then use this.

```
for ele in elements[:20]:
    print(ele.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: Thank you but another very strange think happend ... if I dont have this line 2 times:
driver.get("https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7#balances")
        driver.get("https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7#balances")

I get the same error like on the other answere...:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window

Answer (score 0):

To scrape the top 20 holder of a token on the ERC-20 chain as the *Holders* information is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- `scrollIntoView` the *Token Holders Chart*
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired [`visibility_of_all_elements_located()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60496688/unable-to-locate-element-under-dynamic-comp/60497305#60497305).
- You can use the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  ```
  driver.get("https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7#balances")
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='card']"))))
  WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='tokeholdersiframe']")))
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='table table-md-text-normal table-hover']//tbody//tr//td[./span]/span/a")))[:20]])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['0x7b8c69a0f660cd43ef67948976daae77bc6a019b', 'Binance 7', '0x5754284f345afc66a98fbb0a0afe71e0f007b949', 'Binance', 'Huobi 9', 'Bittrex 3', '0xd545f6eaf71b8e54af1f02dafba6c0d46c491cc1', '0x778476d4c51f93078d61e51c978f90b4a6e500af', 'Bitfinex 2', '0x5041ed759dd4afc3a72b8192c143f72f4724081a', '0xd30b438df65f4f788563b2b3611bd6059bff4ad9', '0x570aeda18a21d8fff6d28a5ef34164553cf9cb77', '0x2b9dc5aaf7b1c15f1fd8aba255919c2a7a184453', '0x6a5b1111a0b5ea8c7ec5665ba09cbacd7fde2b96', 'Gate.io 1', '0x9ec7d40d627ec59981446a6e5acb33d51afcaf8a', '0x231568baa78111377f097bb087241f8379fa18f4', '0xd33547964bae70e1ddd2863a4770dc5cffd86269', 'Huobi 3', 'Compound Tether']
  ```

Comment: Hi thank you but get this exception for the code:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window

But the other answer works

Comment: @MToken There was no window switching in my code you shouldn't see `NoSuchWindowException` anyway. keep your libraries updated.

Comment: What can I say... when i habe two times driver.get(url)... inside of my code it also work with you solution ... But if not:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window

Comment: @MToken You haven't told us about your usecase in details, however I will suggest you to refrain from using `--no-sandbox` and `--disable-dev-shm-using` unless necessary. Those are used in different circumstances.